# How to get a kivy file .kv widget id from a python .py file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

My Kivy app has the following structure:

```
screens/home.py
screens/home.kv
screenmanager.py
screenmanager.kv
main.py
```

Does anyone knows how to get from home.py an id inside home.kv?

```
screenmanager.py    
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
        sm =ScreenManager()
        class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
            pass



screenmanager.kv
<ScreenManager>:  
        id: scrn_mngr
            Home:
                id: home
                name: 'home'

home.kv
<Home>:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDLabel:
            text: "text"
            MDScrollView:
                MDList:
                    id: box

home.py
class Home(MDScreen):
    "I want to get MDList id here!!!"
    pass
```

I tryed everything but with no success. Does anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a method (other than `__init__()`) of `Home` you can use `self.ids.box`.

Or you can define an `ObjectProperty` in the `Home` class:

```
class Home(MDScreen):
    box = ObjectProperty(None)
```

And in the `kv` add that property:

```
<Home>:
    box: box
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDLabel:
            text: "text"
            MDScrollView:
                MDList:
                    id: box
```

Then, `box` can be accessed as an attribute of the `Home` instance.

Comment: Dear John Anderson. Thank you very much for your answer and I think I am in the right way.

Comment: I tryed the first way but the method to get the  access id only works with "Clock.schedule_once(self, get_id, .2)" with this I thing it gives time to the screen creates the id and then I can get it. The ObjectProperty way prints box as Nono and it only works if i use the Clock method as well. Is that right or do I have an straight way for doing it? If you need more of my code just ask. Thank very much once again!

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use that `Clock` method, but you cannot access the `MDList` or the `ids` until they are created.

Comment: Thank you John Anderson Do you know a way to create widget in .kv file before the Python method is called with out Clock or a code logic/extruture for that? Once again Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I cannot understand what you are trying to do. Please post a [mcve] that shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am sorry John Anderson. Your explanation is great! I tryed a little more and I got  how to get the ids. I was with some dificult to understand when ids are created. Thank you very much!